# Passing a template param through to another template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not a programmer, but actually a lawyer who has spent the last year or so learning C++.  I'm doing this as a hobby.  In any case, I've started experimenting with templates and just can't figure out how to do this. I'm implementing a templatized Queue, using a Node Struct, which I also templatize and declare outside the Queue class.  How can I pass the templatized type for the Queue on to the Node struct?  Any other comments in general appreciated. Thank you.
Sample Code:

```
template<class T> struct Node{
Node<T> *next;  T data;
Node<T> * previous;
Node (T d) {data = d;}
};


template<class Q> class Queue
{
    int count;
    Node<Q>  *head;  -> doesn't work -'Node<T>::data uses undefined class Q.  
    Node<Q> *tail;     


public:
    Queue() : count(0), head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}
    ~Queue();


    void Enqueue(Q data);
    Node<Q>* Dequeue();
    std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const;
};

void Queue<class Q>::Enqueue(Q data)
{
    Node<Q> * newNode = new Node<Q>(data);
    if(!head)
        head = tail = newNode;
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        tail->next=NULL;
    }
    ++count;
}

Queue<class Q>::~Queue()
{
        while(head)
        {
            Node<Q> * tmp = head;
            head=head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
}


Node<Q> * Queue<class Q>::Dequeue()
{
    if(!head) return NULL;

    Node<Q> * temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    --count;
    return temp;
}

std::ostream& Queue<class Q>::Print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    if(!head)
    {
        os<<"Empty list"<<endl;
        return os;
    }

    for(Node<Q> *itr = head; itr!=NULL; itr=itr->next)
        os<<" "<<itr->data <<" "<<endl;

    return os;
}


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Queue<Q>& q)
{
   return q.Print(os);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T> struct Node{
Node<T> *next;  T data;
Node<T> * previous;
Node (T d) {data = d;}
};


template<typename Q> class Queue
{
    int count;
    Node<Q>  *head;
    Node<Q> *tail;     


public:
    Queue() : count(0), head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}
    ~Queue();


    void Enqueue(Q data);
    Node<Q>* Dequeue();
    std::ostream& Print(std::ostream& os) const;
};

template<typename Q>
void Queue<Q>::Enqueue(Q data)
{
    Node<Q> * newNode = new Node<Q>(data);
    if(!head)
        head = tail = newNode;
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        tail->next=NULL;
    }
    ++count;
}

template<typename Q>
Queue<Q>::~Queue()
{
        while(head)
        {
            Node<Q> * tmp = head;
            head=head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
}

template<typename Q>
Node<Q> * Queue<Q>::Dequeue()
{
    if(!head) return NULL;

    Node<Q> * temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    --count;
    return temp;
}

template<typename Q>
std::ostream& Queue<Q>::Print(std::ostream& os) const
{
    if(!head)
    {
        os<<"Empty list"<<endl;
        return os;
    }

    for(Node<Q> *itr = head; itr!=NULL; itr=itr->next)
        os<<" "<<itr->data <<" "<<endl;

    return os;
}

template<typename Q>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Queue<Q>& q)
{
   return q.Print(os);
}
```

I fixed the compile errors for you.

Comment: wow that was stupid.  I should have spotted that.  I thought it had something to do with the name lookup rules, etc.   Thank you very much.  BTW, I'm not aware of any difference between typename and class for the template params. Is there a difference in this case I'm missing?